# PriceBookEntry associated with QuoteLineItem

Tags: apex, trigger, quote, quotelineitem

I have created a quote and associated a price book with it in trigger and after that I have created quotelineitems and attached them with quote. But it is not getting any pricebookentry it. Due to that quotelineitems are not getting created.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code is missing at your question which community member can look and guide you appropriately.

Comment: can you share the code? also did you attach the price book to the opportunity?